# App Engine flexible behind a CDN (Fastly)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, app-engine-flexible, fastly

We are running an App Engine Flexible app behind with Fastly (CDN) on the front. We have set up `ghs.googlehosted.com` as the origin server, so the CDN forwards the request to that server if it doesn't have the cached version. This has been running fine for months.

However, we want now to ensure Fastly connects to the origin (`ghs.googlehosted.com`) over TLS. It seems `ghs.googlehosted.com` does not support TLS. Any ideas of how to overcome this situation?

Comment: Shouldn't you set the origin to *your* app's URL instead of `ghs.googlehosted.com` (which serves **all** GAE apps, not only yours)? Also how did you reach the conclusion that TLS is not supported?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if I use myapp.appspot.com as the origin. Google provides `ghs.googlehosted.com` as the CNAME to add, so I used that one and it works when TLS is disabled.

TLS doesn't seem to work - I've checked with `openssl s_client -connect ghs.googlehosted.com:443`

Comment: Have you tried the same with your app's hostname? For mine it shows TLSV1.2

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I get a 404

Comment: It seems the issue is related to the use of the HTTP `Host` header. You get a 404 when you use this header with `myapp.appspot.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, this is what we have found out when choosing the origin host of our CDN (Fastly):

- `myapp.appspot.com`: Supports TLS but requires the `Host` HTTP header to be exactly `myapp.appspot.com`. Therefore, the `Host` header needs to be overridden.
- `ghs.googlehosted.com`: Does not support TLS, but accepts any `Host` HTTP header, so you can use any of your App Engine custom domains.

More info in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/8oamPigGGME) in the App Engine group.

Edit: I was missing sending the SNI in the request. Now it works well with `ghs.googlehosted.com` and TLS.

Comment: how did you determine what SNI to use?